# How to make code supression messages always appear in english?

Tags: visual-studio, localization, roslyn

My project has quite a set of StyleCop/FxCop rules active, and when I violate one, Intellisense suggest me some repair features for whatever I break. If I want to ignore the rule, it can automatically create the suppression. However, these messages always are automatically generated in german, since my OS, language setting and even Visual Studio are in german. I want the comments in the code to be english, though.

Consider this code:

```cs
public static AngleUnit CreateUnit(string unit)
        {
            try
            {
                return CallSomeLegacyFunctionWhichMayThrowRandomExceptions(unit);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}\n\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
            }
            return new AngleUnit("deg", 0.017453292519943295);
        }
```

Correctly, there's a warning on the `catch` that I should not catch `Exception`. To suppress I select `Possible solutions` from the popup, then `Suppress CA1301` and `in source`. I get:

```
            }
#pragma warning disable CA1031 // Keine allgemeinen Ausnahmetypen abfangen
            catch (Exception ex)
#pragma warning restore CA1031 // Keine allgemeinen Ausnahmetypen abfangen
            {
```

If I choose `in source (attribute)` instead, I get:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1031:Keine allgemeinen Ausnahmetypen abfangen", Justification = "<Ausstehend>")]
        public static AngleUnit CreateUnit(string unit)
```

How do I get VS to write out the comments in english? I don't want to manually update these each time. I also don't want to switch my VS or OS to english.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have a way to configure that, but that's a good idea. I've filed a bug at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/51135.